# Which jar and spring version does <mvc:resource> come?

Tags: java, spring

In my application, I am using the tag `<mvc:resource>` but I don't know which jar/version/taglib it comes from:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]
    - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element 
[resources] Offending resource: file 
[G:/WorkSpace/Spring/WechatApp/WebContent/WEB-INF/wechat- servlet.xml]
```

Could you point at appropriate jar/version/taglib?

Comment: check with [`spring-mvc`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE)

Comment: Post your actual xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`spring-mvc`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE)`jar`.

I hope you have added xml namespace correctly as:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
</bean>
```

Comment: I already done this type of name space it is working, But i could not find it is in witch jar version ..

Comment: @Subbareddy: do you want to look for the source of `spring-mvc.xsd` or just curious to know the name of *jar*?

Comment: @Subbareddy: have you been using `maven`?